# IOS LockScreen Play Pause

Tags: ios, audio, audio-streaming

I'm using [StreamingKit](https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit) to play streaming audio, and when I play the song also use **MPNowPlayingInfoCenter** to update the lock screen.

the lock screen shows the pause button and calls the event

```
  - (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent: (UIEvent *) receivedEvent {

   if (receivedEvent.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {

    switch (receivedEvent.subtype) {
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlStop:
            [[AudioPlayer sharedInstance] stop];
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack:
            [[AudioPlayer sharedInstance] next];
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPreviousTrack:
            [[AudioPlayer sharedInstance] prev];
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
            if ([AudioPlayer sharedInstance].status == AudioPlayerStatusPause) {

                [[AudioPlayer sharedInstance] play];
            }else {
                [[AudioPlayer sharedInstance] pause];
            }
            break;

        default: break;
    }
  }
}
```

the pause button stops playback and continues normally but the icon on the lock screen is still to pause as the picture show

*in the image is paused but the audio continues to display the pause button*
[image: image paused]

before I used [DOUAudioStreamer](https://github.com/douban/DOUAudioStreamer) and functioning normally so I think the problem may be [StreamingKit](https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit),the only thing I want is to change the pause button for one play in the lock screen.

I am a beginner, I hope your help thanks.

Comment: Another problem is that in iOS 7 this behavior has changed. Your code won't work on an iOS 7 device because the lock screen does not send UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause any more.

Comment: if it is true but it works because add "UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay" and "UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause"

Comment: Very good, that's what you needed to fix that part! :)

Comment: the problem is that the pause button does not change to play but if it works

Comment: Same problem did not work any solution.